# splitting serialport data into different textboxes C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm new to c#.

I'm using the Nucleo board to send data through a serial port into my GUI. The data consists of pulse rate, number of steps and body temperature.

My code here works completely fine to display all the data into a **single** textbox, **but I want to display each value in different textboxes**.

This is what the incoming data looks like

```
S0E // where "S" is for steps and "E" is for the end 
P5E  //  where "P" is for pulse rate and "E" is for the end 
T22.5E //  where "T" is for body temp. and "E" is for the end
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
  private void showbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    //Showbtn click
    {
        text.Clear();   //clears the text in the textbox
        bool foundUser = false;   // sets the boolean foundUser to false
        int userindex = 0; // sets interger to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < userlist.Count; i++)   
        {
            if (userlist[i].name.Equals(Nametb.Text))  // if the user entered name equals to the name in the list
            {
                foundUser = true;
                userindex = i;
            }
        }
        if (foundUser == true)
        {
            string userText;     // the following lines of code displays the user details in the textbox
            userText = "name :" + userlist[userindex].name + "user :" + Environment.NewLine + "age:" + userlist[userindex].age +
                Environment.NewLine + " gender:" + userlist[userindex].gender + Environment.NewLine + "height:" + userlist[userindex].height + 
                Environment.NewLine + "weight:" + userlist[userindex].weight + Environment.NewLine + "BMI :" + userlist[userindex].bmI;
            text.Text = userText;
        }
        else
        {
            text.Text = "no user found";  // if the user not found displays as "no user Found"
        }

        t = comboBox1.Text.ToString();

        sErial(t);
    }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   // searches for available com ports
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(port);   // adds them to the combo box
        }
    }
    string t;   
    private SerialPort SerialPort1;


    void sErial(string Port_name)
    {
        SerialPort1 = new SerialPort(Port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);    //serial port properties
        SerialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);   
        SerialPort1.Open();   //opens serial port
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort1 = (SerialPort)sender;

        string w = serialPort1.ReadLine();   // assigns the data from the serial port to a string


        if (w != String.Empty)
        {
            if (abort == false)
            {

                Invoke(new Action(() => rt1.AppendText(w)));   // displays the data in a textbox
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you receive data from an external device and you wish to split apart a string that contains multiple numeric data elements delimited by single characters, so you can display the results to different textboxes.

This is a typical problem to be solved by people who receive data from an embedded system and need to learn how to handle it on a host PC, but are new to programming in C#.

There are many different ways to do this. Since you say you can receive and display the entire string in a single textbox, I will focus only on how to split it apart and display the parts in three different richTextBoxes.

For a c# beginner, `string.split` and `substring` are pretty straightforward ways to break apart a string. Here is one simple example using string.split.

I made a complete example for you: you can see below that it works. First I created a form containing three rich textboxes called rt1, rt2, and rt3, along with an input textbox called tbInput and a button called btnSplit.

Then in the designer I double-clicked on the button to add an event handler for btnInput_click and added the code below to that handler. That's it!

[image]

```
private void btnSplit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string blah = tbInput.Text;
    tbInput.Clear();
    var lst = blah.ToUpper().Split('E').ToList();
    foreach (var item in lst)
        if (item.Trim().StartsWith("S"))
            rt1.AppendText($"Steps: {item.Remove(0, 1)} \n");
        else if (item.Trim().StartsWith("T"))
            rt2.AppendText($"Temperature: {item.Remove(0, 1)} \n");
        else if (item.Trim().StartsWith("P"))
            rt3.AppendText($"Pulse: {item.Remove(0, 1)} \n");
}
```

The code converts the input to upper case, splits the string on the letter "E" and assigns the results to a list, so given the starting string containing three "E"s, you will now have a list containing three strings:

```
item01 == S111
item02 == T98.6
item03 == P70
```

I then trim leading and trailing white space and assign the result to one of three RichTextBoxes based on the leading character. I use `item.Remove(0,1)` to remove the leading character before appending the result to the textbox. I use interpolation to embed the result in a string of my choosing.

I should probably point out that unless you are running this code on a thread other than the UI thread, you do not need to use an Action delegate and you do not need to Invoke anything. If you're on the main thread, just append the text to the textbox.

If you *are* planning to make a cross-thread call to a control running on the UI, an `Action<>` delegate is not the right way to do this. If that's what you're trying to do, look at `MethodInvoker()`. However, I strongly recommend that you not try to use multiple threads until you are quite advanced as a programmer and have read several books on the subject. They certainly are not needed for a simple project like this one :)

Does this help?

Comment: hello, thanks a lot for your time.  but  I'm sorry for some reasons, it wouldn't display the values in the text boxes at all.

Comment: Well, when I put it into a WInForms application with three textboxes, my code displays what it should display. Is your problem that you can't display any text in multiple textboxes?

Comment: I added a full demo example to assist anybody else coming along.  Of course I wasn't going to read the serial port in a demo because there would be no data on mine :) . If my response helped you solve this, please upvote and/or choose it as the correct answer.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

@craig.Feied

this was the part which I altered. 
thanks again for your help.

```
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort1 = (SerialPort)sender;

                var rt1 = new RichTextBox();
                var rt2 = new RichTextBox();
                var rt3 = new RichTextBox();
                string blah = serialPort1.ReadLine();

                var lst = blah.Split('E').ToList();
                foreach (var item in lst)
                    if (item.Trim().StartsWith("S"))
                        rt1.AppendText($"Steps: {item.Remove(0, 1)} \n");
                    else if (item.Trim().StartsWith("T"))
                        rt2.AppendText($"Temperature: {item.Remove(0, 1)} \n");
                    else if (item.Trim().StartsWith("P"))
                        rt3.AppendText($"Pulse: {item.Remove(0, 1)} \n");

        }
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you got an answer to your question, don't forget to come back and mark it as the answer.